# When were Swift and Voltaire discovered?

Tags: mars, crater, deimos

[Deimos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deimos_(moon)) -- Mars' smallest moon -- has only two named features: the Swift crater and the Voltaire crater. Based on the [Gazetteer of Planetary Nomenclature](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Feature/5789), their names were approved in 1973.

Given the size of these craters, I assume they weren't discovered until the space age. Perhaps during a Mariner flyby? When were these craters first discovered?

Answer (score 3):

[NASA says about the Mariner 9](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars-exploration/missions/mariner-8-9/):

> The spacecraft also provided the first closeup pictures of the two small, irregular Martian moons: Phobos and Deimos.

This must have happened somewhere between November 14th, 1971 and October 27th, 1972. [Here](https://www.planetary.org/space-images/deimos-from-mariner-9) is a picture from January 27th, 1972 which shows them:

[image]

FWIW, the only other spacecraft to reach Mars between then and 1973 was the Russian [Mars 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2).